# How To Make a Drop down which conains grid item when cklicked in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

am making a category app where there will be a lot of dropdowns and on clicked it should display a list of subcategories in grid view here is a sample image of what I want to achieve.

https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/1502567/screenshots/7147539/media/dbca2b397050acac918164ddfc5820cd.jpg

Answer (score 0):

That example doesn't seem like much of a dropdown, more like a container for a grid of items? I would use a `Table` to contain all these items. Flutter.dev has really good documentation on how to use it: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Table-class.html

```
bool pressed;

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[    
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text("button"),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                pressed = true;
              });
            },
          )
          // show table if pressed is true, otherwise show an empty widget
          pressed ? Table() : SizedBox(), 
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: I want the items to be displayed in a grid when clicked the dropdown button

Comment: You can have a variable that controls whether or not the button has been clicked, and display the `Table` only if that boolean is true with a ternary operator. I edited the answer to add that extra information.